# Compound sentence with adjective clause

Tags: compound-subjects

Wanted to know whether the following sentence is a compound sentence.

> *These apples look very red and juicy.*

Specifically, can this sentence be read as below and therefore marked as a compound sentence?

> These apples very red and these apples look very juicy

Comment: Yes, your second example is a compound sentence; at least it would be  if you were to add the verb "look" to the first coordinate: _These apples **look** very red and these apples look very juicy_.But there's no adjective clause -- where did you get that idea from? –

Comment: Thank you. But, what about the first sentence? Is that a compound sentence?

Comment: No, it's a simple sentence. There is only one verb. Also, why do you think there's an adjective clause?

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps, because of 'red' and 'juicy'. Will 'look very red and juicy' be an adverbial clause because it tells us more about 'look'? Or will it be just the predicate?

Comment: "Look" is one of the verbs that can take a predicative complement. In "These apples look [very red and juicy]" the expression "very red and juicy" is not a clause but an **adjective phrase** functioning as a subjective complement -- it is ascribing the property of being "very red and juicy" to the subject "these apples".

Comment: A compound sentence is one where there are two independent clauses joined by a conjunction. These apples look red and juicy **and** those apples look rotten and awful. She looks nice but her sister looks stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Compound sentences can stand alone when separated. You are right but with a little change:

> These apples *look* very red 
>  These apples *look* very juicy

The conjunction *'and'* is in between 'red' and 'juicy'; so, you need to separate them.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is a simple sentence, with an adjective phrase including two adjectives compounded with "and".

The second sentence is a compound sentence, or it would be if you repeated "look":

> These apples look very red and these apples look very juicy.

The meanings of the simple sentence and the compound sentence are the same, but in practice you'd never use the compound sentence.